# Sharepoint TaxonomyField Object

Tags: sharepoint

How do you get a TaxonomyField object from the Managed Property Title? Does anyone know a good article/tutorial on programatically working with taxonomies in Sharepoint 2010?

Answer (score -1):

Thanks Per Jakobsen for answering this. Click on the below link to find his answer.
[Sharepoint TaxonomyField Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872892/sharepoint-taxonomyfield-object)

Comment: You linked to your own question.